# Using osm2po to solve Travelling Salesman Problem

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2po, travelling-salesman

I've got a Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP) to solve. I created a routable street graph using osm2po and imported the result to PostGIS.
On my PG db I installed the pgrouting extension (over PGAdmin3 GUI --> right click Extension-->pgrouting).

I've got a second table with a visits_id (places to be visited) and the nearest node_id (node_id from osm2po).

How can I solve the TSP which seems to be build into osm2po already?

a.) I couldn't find any document how to do it in TSP.

b.) Do I have to install an additional function or something in my PostGIS? Or is installing pgrouting via unix-terminal and enabling it in PGAdmin3 enough?

c.) Do I solve the tsp via the osm2po inbuild tsp-algorithm or using pgrouting?

Comment: What lead you to the "TSP which seems to be build into osm2po already" part?

Comment: Hi Brad,
this post leads me to the assumption:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29530/looking-for-tsp-with-target-different-from-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you decide to use **pgRouting** for TSP the answers to your questions are:

a) pgRouting's [documentation for TSP](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/tsp/doc/index.html#pgr-tsp)

b) When you install pgRouting with `CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;`, then the TSP function is available, too.

c) This decision is up to you.